# How to get a List<JsonPath> from restassured JsonPath

Tags: java, generics, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using restassured framework, and inside it, it has JsonPath class.
JsonPath has a method signature of getList(String path, Class T);

I have attempt to do something like this:

```
List<JsonPath> myList = myJsonPathObject.getList("mypath", JsonPath.class);
```

And I get a runtime casting exception. So what would be the correct format in calling this.
I also attempted:

```
List<JsonPath> myList = myJsonPathObject.getList("mypath", new ArrayList<JsonPath>().getClass());
```

And that also failed. Actually that failed compilation.

Answer (score 2):

JsonPath is used to extract values out of a JSON document. You cannot get a list of "JsonPath" out of JSON document.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to support what you just claimed. A json is a markup of objects and sub objects, essentially json are markup of json within json, so I do not see why you can not get a list of json out of a json.

Comment: Well I'm the founder of the framework so I've implemented the JsonPath that's shipped with Rest Assured so know that it's not supported. It's possible that it's supported in other frameworks. A colleague of mine has implemented another JsonPath (http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) that doesn't use the Groovy syntax and maybe it supports doing what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old threat, but someone commented and reminded me of this. I actually found an answer to this question.

What I had to do was cast it into a `Map<String, Object>` and while iterating through the objects, I have to cast the object into the appropriate class.

```
Map<String, Object> myMap = (Map<String, Object>) myJsonPathObject.get("mypath");
for (String key : myMap.getKeySet()) {
  Map<String, Object> subMyMap = (Map<String, Object>) myMap.get(key);
}
```

So now I can continue to get additional mockup, json within a json.